# How to get all lables with language subtags?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

For example, if I ask for cities with Chinese labels with

```
SELECT (COUNT (?label) as ?labels)
{
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q515 ;
          rdfs:label ?label .
    
#FILTER (LANG(?label) = "zh")
FILTER LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "zh")
    
}
```

I'll get over 6K with "zh" without subtags and over 20K with subtags. Is there a SPARQL way (not using the language service) to get all labels with subtags?

Some SPARQL engines except `FILTER LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "zh*")` but it seems that's implementation specific.

Comment: `FILTER (LANG(?label) != "zh") .
FILTER LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "zh")`?

Comment: Indeed that will work but I was curious if there was a way to get it only with `LANGMATCHES` which, now I realize, wasn't obvious in the I put the question.

Comment: "*" in subtags is extended filtering described in RFC4647 section 3.3.2, whereas only basic filtering described in 3.3.1 has to be supported according to spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches

Comment: And [yet...](http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+*%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fs+%3FanyLabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++++%3FanyLabel+rdfs%3AsubPropertyOf*+rdfs%3Alabel+.%0D%0A++%0D%0AFILTER+LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%2C+%22en*%22%29%0D%0A%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)

Comment: And by the way, the current RDC is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646.txt  but both to this and to the previous RDF and SPARQL are partially complaint it seems.